# can't pass an object into a component because of subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

i'm having a problem: i call a post request that saves in the db an object and takes in input a json that basically has the values of the object that i want to save, (the db does it), but after that i want my servlet to return the object that it saved because i need the id if it(the id is the only value that is generated in the back-end)
the code of the servlet called by the angular cli component is:

```
postprogetti(raw: any,cli:cliente,gr:any,fp:any,comp:any){
    var prog = '{'  +'"id":'+'0'+','+'"nome":'+'"'+raw[0]+'"'+','+'"cli":'+JSON.stringify(cli)+',"setCompetenze_prog":'+JSON.stringify(comp)+','+'"SetFigProf"'+':'+JSON.stringify(fp)+  ',"SetGruppo":'+JSON.stringify(gr)+'}'
    const obj = JSON.parse(prog);
    console.log("obj ->"+ JSON.stringify(obj))
    var res = this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/postprogetto_competenze_figprof', obj).subscribe(
        (val) => {
            console.log("andata", val);
        })
       
}
```

> console.log("andata", val);
> this prints the data that i want to come back to the component, how can i edit the code for make this function return this data? thanks

EDIT:imports?
[image]

Comment: Can't the method just be concerned with making the api call? Subscribe to it in the component and do what ever you need to with the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the concept of promises, in order to get the data.

```
postprogetti(raw: any,cli:cliente,gr:any,fp:any,comp:any){
 return new Promise(function(resolve){
      var prog = '{'  +'"id":'+'0'+','+'"nome":'+'"'+raw[0]+'"'+','+'"cli":'+JSON.stringify(cli)+',"setCompetenze_prog":'+JSON.stringify(comp)+','+'"SetFigProf"'+':'+JSON.stringify(fp)+  ',"SetGruppo":'+JSON.stringify(gr)+'}'
      const obj = JSON.parse(prog);
      console.log("obj ->"+ JSON.stringify(obj))
      var res = this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/postprogetto_competenze_figprof', obj).subscribe(
          (val) => {
              console.log("andata", val);
              resolve(val)
          })
 });
       
}


// to get the data
postprogetti.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: ok i'm trying your code but i don't know from whitch module i have to import it, ide gives me many choises, as "dns", "path", "url" and others, what do i chose?

Comment: so the function resolve waits for the data to be aviable and then sends them to the component, right?

Comment: kind of @pietro, I've wrapped all you code inside a promise. A promise can be resolved later in time when needed. `resolved` means trigger completion of block, similar to `return` keyword

Comment: ok, thanks, and which import should i use? please look at the question, i'm about to edit it, thanks

Comment: @pietro you don't have to import anything to use `resolve`. it is a function paramount which is provided by `promise``.

Comment: @pietro for reference https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp

Comment: thank you, but if i understood this metod does not return an object to the controller but a parameter of type unknown, am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do one thing. You can just return the observable you are getting from the call of this post request. and then you can just subscribe to that observable in other files of functions on the same file. something like below

```
    postprogetti(raw: any,cli:cliente,gr:any,fp:any,comp:any){
    var prog = '{'  +'"id":'+'0'+','+'"nome":'+'"'+raw[0]+'"'+','+'"cli":'+JSON.stringify(cli)+',"setCompetenze_prog":'+JSON.stringify(comp)+','+'"SetFigProf"'+':'+JSON.stringify(fp)+  ',"SetGruppo":'+JSON.stringify(gr)+'}'
    const obj = JSON.parse(prog);
    console.log("obj ->"+ JSON.stringify(obj))
     //returning onservable on below line. 
     return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/postprogetto_competenze_figprof', obj);
       
}
```

Now in the same file or other files after calling this function you need to subscribe to it. just like below

```
 postprogetti(raw,cli,gr,fp,comp).subscribe((response) => {
     if(response) {
        console.log('response', response);
     }
    }, (error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```